# Is there any equivalent for Raster.getSample(int, int, int) in Android?

Tags: java, android, raster

I need to write a Project in Android, with an existing Java-Code-Fragment.
In these, `Raster.getSample(int x, int y, int b)` is used.
The 3rd Parameter is the band, of the Pixel.

To get these running in Android, i use `Bitmap` instead of `Raster`.
But know i can only use getPixels(int, int). How can i extract the band?
Is there any other Class or Method i can use?

Old Code:

```
Raster rasterData;
y_ = rasterData.getSample(x + 1, row, 0);
```

New Code:

```
Bitmap rasterData;
y_ = rasterData.getPixels(x + 1, row);
...?...
```

I how someon have an idea.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use methods `red`, `greeen`, `blue` and `alpha` of [Color class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html)

```
Bitmap rasterData;
int y_ = rasterData.getPixel(x + 1, row);
int red = Color.red(y_);
```